# What is the list file (*.f) for verilog?

Tags: verilog

I found both ncvlog and Verdi can read the design through *.f which includes *.v files and  +incdir commands. It's easy to get an example and modify it fit the new project.

However, is there have any specific description about .f file?

Answer (score 2):

Commonly referred to as "dot-f" files, files that end with an extension of `.f` contain command-line arguments for the simulator.  The `.f` extension is actually just a convention and not required by the tools.  The the file is passed in with a `-f` or `-F` option.

Any command-line argument that the tool accepts can be placed within a file that is passed with the `-f` option.

Here is an excerpt from an old ncvlog manual I found online:

> `-File arguments_filename`
>
> Use the command-line arguments contained in the specified arguments file.
>   You can store frequently used or lengthy command lines by putting command-line arguments
>   (command options and top-level design unit names) in a text file. When you invoke the
>   elaborator with the -file option, the arguments in the arguments file are incorporated with
>   your command as if they had been entered on the command line.
>   The arguments file can contain command options, including other -file options, and
>   top-level design unit names. The individual arguments within the arguments file must be
>   separated by white space or comments.

As an example, the following two scenarios are equivalent:

### Specify command-line arguments directly

```
$> ncvlog +incdir+foo mod1.v mod2.v mod3.v
```

### Specify command-line arguments in a .f file

#### args.f:

```
+incdir+foo
mod1.v
mod2.v
mod3.v
```

`$> ncvlog -f args.f`

Comment: That is not only a list file. It can contains of any command option of the tool, like ncverilog's options. Different tools have specific options, so it is better to move tool-specific command in the command line, and put common options in the list file.

Answer (score 0):

it's just some arguments, you can put file list, include directory, macro define, and other option here